# CountIF within an Array VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, countif

This should be easy and I think I am almost there. I would like to count how many times an entry repeats itself within a certain array. The array will be populated from a range. Eventually if the number of the count is more than 4, I would like to insert "Excess", otherwise if less than 4, I would like to insert "Insufficient", else is "complete". Unfortunately, even though I have learnt to do these calculations without using Arrays, I find some difficulties when switching to Arrays.

How the code should look like

```
Sub test()
    Dim MyArray() As Variant, Countarrays() As Variant, Result() As Variant
    Dim r As Range
    Dim rows As Integer

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Set r = Range("B2", Range("B1").End(xlDown))
    MyArray = Range("B2", Range("B1").End(xlDown))
    rows = Range("B2", Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Count

    For i = 0 To rows
        For j = 0 To rows
        Countarrays(i, 1) = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(r, MyArray(i))

        If (Countarrays(i, 1).value) > 4 Then Result(j, 1) = "Excess"
        ElseIf (Countarrays(i, 1).value) < 4 Then Result(j, 1) = "Insufficient"
        ElseIf (Countarrays(i, 1).value) = 4 Then Result(j, 1) = "Complete"
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You can't directly use `COUNTIF` or whatever Excel function as such on a 2 dimensional array, populating an array from a range creates a 2 dimensional array. So you need a workaround.

Comment: repeats itself within a row or a column? Or within entire array?

Comment: What about using a dictionary? You could add each unique item to your dictionary, and then increases the value everytime the item repeats. After that, loop trough your dictionary, If value of item <4 then `Insufficient` elseif >4 then `Excess` Else `Complete`. You can even know how many is the `Excess` (2,3,4...units) and same for `Insufficient`. About Dictionaries in VBA, check [Excel VBA Dictionary – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim MyArray, DictDuplicates As New Scripting.Dictionary, i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'change if needed
        MyArray = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown))
        For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray) 'loop to store all the items and how many times do they repeat
            If Not DictDuplicates.Exists(MyArray(i, 2)) Then 'if doesn't exists will store it
                DictDuplicates.Add MyArray(i, 2), 1
            Else 'if it does exists will increment its item value
                DictDuplicates(MyArray(i, 2)) = DictDuplicates(MyArray(i, 2)) + 1
            End If
        Next i

        For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray) 'loop to give back the result
            Select Case DictDuplicates(MyArray(i, 2))
                Case Is > 4
                    MyArray(i, 1) = "Excess"
                Case Is = 4
                    MyArray(i, 1) = "Complete"
                Case Is < 4
                    MyArray(i, 1) = "Insufficient"
            End Select
        Next i
        .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown)) = MyArray
    End With

End Sub
```

Note that for the `DictDuplicates` to work, you need to check the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` library.

Comment: Although it works as a charm, could you please explain me also how to use late binding in preventing to check the Microsoft Scripting Runtime all the times?

Comment: @Alessio_110 [here](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html) you can find anything on dictionaries, is really helpful.